# connectionStrings in app.config at compile time

Tags: c#, wpf, msbuild, connection-string

I'm working with a WPF application, and I have a connection string with hardcoded database parameters in my app.config file.  What happens to this app.config at compile time? Is this packaged with the rest of my application? Is there any security vulnerabilities to having the hardcoded username/password for the database in my connectionString or is there something I should be doing with this when I build the application for production?

I just want to make sure I'm not exposing connection information to the average user that they shouldn't have in the first place.

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/encrypting-passwords-in-a-net-app-config-file

Comment: Yes you are exposing connection information to the user.    If the connection string is anywhere in the application is can be hacked.  Even if you hard coded the setting in the application and compiled users could get to that information.

Comment: I guess my question would be then, is storing connection information for a desktop app in app.config best practice if this is encrypted, or is there a more secure way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `app.config` is renamed during compilation to `myApplication.Exe.Config` assuming your Exe name is `myApplication`. It is not an embedded resource and the user can view and change all the information within it.